# Adding padding to the bottom

Tags: css

I am trying to make the the ads at the **bottom** of the [website](http://www.apptec.net) to be aligned with the content(i.e to have the same `padding-right` as the posts have.) but even after adding the it to the same `div`, I am unable to do so,
Here is my code,

```
<script class="mcolumn-pad" type="text/javascript"><!--
//ad goes here
</script>
```

Comment: Hello Akito haven't solved issues?

Comment: @Pankaj: Haha, this is another one of the same kind. Expected you :)

Comment: Put that ads div inside : <div id="dynamic-content" class="outline fix"> right now its not in this div

Comment: @Pankaj: Thankyou so much once again. If you can post it as an answer I can mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: there is a comment left unclosed see in your page, at the bottom

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing out. I have seen it but was unable to determine which one it was. I will debug it now.

Comment: @Akito - Consider adding some of the HTML from the ad to your question, before you modified it, so that this can serve as a resource to others who encounter this problem as well. Since your link will change over time, and in fact already has, your question may not be as useful to others without seeing the original code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your ads div in

```
<div id="dynamic-content" class="outline fix">
```

Right now its not in the same div, that's why working/showing abnormal.

Answer (score 1):

`script` defines a script block for running embedded JavaScript code. You can't style the script block. However, what you can do is use a debugger like Firebug or Chrome to **examine the HTML that is generated by that script block.**

It looks like your script block generates some HTML with an `ins` element:

```
<div id="page-main">
    ...
    <ins style="left:180px;display:inline-table;border:none;height:90px;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;visibility:visible;width:728px">
```

The ins element has no class or id attributes, but it is a child of a div that has an id attribute, so an easy way to target it with a CSS rule is as follows:

```
div#page-main ins {
    left:180px;
}
```

I'll leave it up to you to tweak the pixel value to align it as per your preference. You can move right by increasing the pixel value, and left by decreasing the pixel value.

Comment: I tried following it and it works fine but when I increase or decrease the size of the page, it becomes weird. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It has inline CSS setting the height to 90px, yet the external CSS is probably messing with the font/line-height such that it is too tall for 90px.

```
#header .outline {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
  zoom: 1;
  z-index: 15;
  height: auto !important; /* <-- add this */
}
```

!important is the only way to override inline styles.